# Chitin, homo or heteropolysaccharide?

Tags: carbohydrates

My teacher told me that Chitin is a heteropolysaccharide but my book regards it as a homopolysaccharide.I am so confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even teachers are sometimes wrong. ;)

Chitin is a [homopolysaccharide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homopolysaccharide). This just means that it is made up of repeating units of the same monosaccharide - in this case that monosaccharide is N-acetylglucosamine. Other examples of homopolysaccharides are glycogen and cellulose.

The basic structure of chitin is shown below as a polymer of two N-acetylglucosamine units:
[image]

Homopolysaccharides can be linear chains or branched, as long as they are made up of just one type of sugar unit. A heteropolysaccharide is made up of multiple different monosaccharide units. [Glycosaminoglycans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycosaminoglycan) would be an example of a heterpolysaccharide as they contain two different sugar units.